# Get Value of Table Row with Button Click Using jQuery - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a table inside of my view. I want to get the text from a row with a button click. So far I am not having any success. The most progress I've made is getting the responses "[object object]" and "Extras 1". There's a value in my model named "Extras", I don't know where the '1' came from.
I've seen others use a hidden field to get the value, but still no luck.

My goal is to use jQuery to get the text from the row with my button click. Thanks for your help!

My View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Select</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Extras)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSelect">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        Select
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td id="tdExtras">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Extras)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Extras);
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in my jQuery I've tried to get the value with .val() and .text() - targeting "Extras" like:

```
$('#Extras').val();
```

to my understanding Extras is the ID. In the Chrome dev tools the html looks like:

```
<button>
    <input id="#" value="the text that I want to select" />
</button>
```

I've also tried setting a class and id to the hidden field inside of my button. All of the values are there, but I can't get access to them. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `class` here instead of `id` and then when button is clicked get closest `tr` and then find input value using `.find()` method of jquery.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//on click of button
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
  //get closest tr then find .tdExtras > input 
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.tdExtras  input').val());
  //or by class 
 console.log("By class -- "+$(this).closest('tr').find('.tdExtras  input.extras').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Select</td>
      <td>
        Abcd
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSelect">  Select </button>
      </td>
      <!--use class instead of id-->
      <td class="tdExtras">

        <input type="text" class="extras" value="something">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSelect">   Select</button>
      </td>
      <td class="tdExtras">
        <input type="text" class="extras" value="something1">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had to do some slight modifications to get it working, but overall your code put me on the right track. Thanks!